# Populate from a child form to an another childform

Tags: c#, mdi

In my project, I have a mdi container `mdiMother` whith two `childform` *(mdiChild1 and mdiChild2)*. The `mdiChild1` have a `listview` *(mode view detail)*. The `mdiChild2` have a button who goal to populate the `listview` in `mdiChild1`.

I have done some peace of code. I copy this code into the `mdiChild1`, create a button, try it and it s works *(mean: I see the `listview` populate)*.

**My problem:**
When I press button from `mdiChild2`, my `listview` isn't populate with same code in `mdiChild1` the code do the job.

Comment: You need to add the code that's working and not working before anyone can help you.

Comment: Please show us your code. How are you actually populating the `ListView`? How are you accessing the `ListView` control in `mdiChild1` from `mdiChild2`?

Comment: @odyss-jii have a look there https://gist.github.com/c6cbcf30dbb355ec9636

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt have a look there https://gist.github.com/c6cbcf30dbb355ec9636

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must control child's controls from `mdiMother`.

Create `static` instance from each `mdiChild`, after that when you want to call method from each of them you must use from these `static` instances.

Like this:

```
public class mdiMother{
    public static mdiChild1 ch1;
    public static mdiChild2 ch2;

    public mdiMother(){
       ch1 = new mdiChild1();
       ch2 = new mdiChild2();
    }
}

public class mdiChild1{
    public void Do(){
       // fill list
    }
}

public class mdiChild2{
    public void CallMdiChild1(){
       mdiMother.ch1.Do();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok I see. So the thing I didn't do: no declare static into mdiMother. I just declare static instance and use it. My problem still same. Some peace of code:      public void addItemToDownload(string item)
        {
            ListViewItem theItem = new ListViewItem(item);
            theItem.SubItems.Add("en attente");
            listDownload.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { theItem });
        }

Comment: is the code I call for populate the listview ... i add a buton in this form, the method works. When i call it from mdiChild2 throught static instance from mdiMother ... don't work ... what's wrong ? Or may it come of the way I call the mdiChild1 from mdiMother mdiChild1 mdChild1 = new mdiChild1();
            mdChild1.MdiParent = this;
            mdChild1.Show();

Comment: You must not create new instance of mdiChilds anywhere. If you do it this way then you have problem in populate listview. Share your code to solve it.

Comment: Nothing exist in this page

Answer (score 0):

Thank to all. I solve my problem and I see it was so stupid. Tha way it's didn't populate: dont refere to the good form. For doing the job, i make a ref to the active mdi child ... and it's work :)

Thanx all for your help... and many thanx to Ahmad who's giving to me the good way to find the solve :p